# Jasmine - why spec fails (related to initialization, before statements, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Sorry for the title. I just am seeing some interesting behavior I want to understand. Code:

```
var element; 

var testFunction = (function() {
  var mount = false;

  return {
    act: function() {
      if (mount == false) {
        element = $("#element")
        element.click(function() {
          console.log("detected click")
        })
        mount = true
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

It's important for me that the actions in `testFunction.act` only run ONCE hence the use of `mount`. One of the many use cases this achieves, is that in test code, if we call `testFunction.act` multiple times, there aren't multiple click handlers that are attached, which would be problematic since you're only expecting to trigger click, not multiple.

The presence of `mount` however, is causing another phenomenon, where only the first spec passes.

Spec:

```
fdescribe("testFunction", function() {
  beforeAll(function() {
    element_spec = affix("#element")
    testFunction.act();
  })
  describe("first spec", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      console.log("first spec")
      console.log(element.length)
      element_spec.click()
    })
    it("should write in console", function() {
    })
  })
  describe("second spec", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      console.log("second spec")
      console.log(element.length)
      element_spec.click()
    })
    it("should write in console", function() {
    })
  })        
});
```

My understanding of what should be happening when the test runs:

1. the `beforeAll` calls `testFunction.act` which saves `element` and binds a click handler to it
2. in the first spec, the saved `element` which had an event handler bound per #1 is called
3. in the second spec, the same thing happens again as in the first spec

However, from the `console.log` output, it's clear that the first click triggers the click handler, the second does not, even though they're both acting on the same saved `element` that is present (`length == 1`) for both tests.

```
first spec
1
detected click
second spec
1
```

I can further confirm this noting that if I make 2 changes: 1) remove the `mount` element in `testFunction.act`, and 2) change the `beforeAll` to `beforeEach`, then I get the expected `console.log` output:

```
first spec
1
detected click
second spec
1
detected click
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
element.click(function() {
      console.log("detected click")
    })
```

its not binds. its dispatch click.

if you want bind, do this instead:

```
element.addEventListener("click",function(){console.log("detected click")});
```

Comment: `.click()` should bind. see docs here: https://api.jquery.com/click/. Also if it didn't, the `console.log` shouldn't have outputted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, there is a substantial difference between `beforeAll` and `beforeEach` [refer](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction#section-Setup_and_Teardown)

For each spec, the `dom` will be rendered fresh and the old context is lost. So for every test you need to freshly attach the event listener.

In your implementation, `mount` being a closure variable does not allow the "event attachment" more than once.

So the right implementation would be to remove the "closure" variable. You should be able to get the "expected result" with "beforeAll".

Comment: so just to be clear, by this logic, `beforeAll` should never have any kind of `affix` to the DOM, since the dom is rendered before each test and `beforeAll` is only called once; is that correct? I did read the reference docs, but didn't find this mentioned...